# How can I detect if a message payload is a non-repeatable-stream, in order to avoid reading it?

Tags: mule4

I have a Mule 4 Custom Policy that will be applied broadly to multiple APIs.
Some of those APIs might be used on Mule apps that have an HTTP Listener with  configured.

For those HTTP-Listeners, I'd like to avoid reading the payload so I don't consume it and affect the application.

How can I detect if the payload is non-repeatable-stream?

### Edit: (Removed extra distracting questions, and add more info)

If non-repeatable-stream is detected, the custom policy would avoid reading the payload in order to NOT interfere with the original transaction.

Comment: You are probably already aware that asking multiple questions in one can cause the question to be closed because it lacks focus.

Comment: What would you do if the payload is not contained in a repeatable stream?

Comment: @aled, sorry I wasn't aware of that, I'll amend my question to focus on the main question.

I would avoid reading the payload and log the incident.